# Issue with VPImageCropperViewController API

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am going to share my image to Instagram , but before sharing in need to user crop their own photo , so I used `VPImageCropperViewController` (https://github.com/windshg/VPImageCropper) to crop the image first then share it to Instagram but the result is over scaled image :

Crop area :

[image]

and the result :

[image]

here is my codes :

```
- (IBAction)shareIt:(id)sender {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(captureView.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
    [captureView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage * screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    VPImageCropperViewController *imgCropperVC = 
    [[VPImageCropperViewController alloc] 
     initWithImage:image
     cropFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100.0f, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.width) 
     limitScaleRatio:3.0];

    imgCropperVC.delegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:imgCropperVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

VPImageCropperDelegate

```
- (void)imageCropper:(VPImageCropperViewController *)cropperViewController didFinished:(UIImage *)editedImage {    
[cropperViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

    NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://location?id=1"];

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {            
        NSURL *url;
        docFile.delegate = self;

        //Save image to directory
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage.jpg"];

        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(editedImage);
        [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];

        //load image
        NSString *getImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage.jpg"];
        UIImage *tempImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:getImagePath];

        //Hook it with Instagram
        NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Image.ig"];
        [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(tempImage, 1.0) writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];

        url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:jpgPath];
        docFile = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
        [docFile setUTI:@"com.instagram.photo"];
        docFile.annotation = @{@"InstagramCaption" : @" #geometrica" };
        [docFile presentOpenInMenuFromRect:self.view.bounds inView:self.view animated:YES];

    }else {        
        UIAlertView *errorToShare = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Instagram unavailable " message:@"You need to install Instagram" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [errorToShare show];
    }    
}];
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should be using the actual pixels of the image for cropping instead of the view's ones?

Comment: Something wrong with `image` and `screenshot` variables. What variable  do you pass to crop view controller? What is the size of this image?

Comment: @vokilam the size of screenshot and image 2 is size of screen,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figure it out to crop image size there is a method in project demo called :

```
- (UIImage *)imageByScalingAndCroppingForSourceImage:(UIImage *)sourceImage targetSize:(CGSize)targetSize;
```

you can mention your target images size with it some thing like this :

```
image = [self imageByScalingAndCroppingForSourceImage:image targetSize:CGSizeMake(1024, 1024)];
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the error here lies in the instatiation of your `imgCropperVC`. You are telling the cropper to crop out a specific rectangle (with your yellow border's size) from the image you are providing. Since you said in a comment here that the size of the picture is the same size as the screen, and since your result seems to be EXACTLY half of the width (it's cropped directly through his face), I sugges trying

```
[[VPImageCropperViewController alloc] 
 initWithImage:image
 cropFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100.0f, self.view.frame.size.width*2,self.view.frame.size.width*2) 
 limitScaleRatio:3.0];
```

This might have something to do with `@2x`, though I'm not really sure this solves your issue for other images and in general.

I suspect the original picture to be bigger than the screen, and scaled down to fit it. If this is correct, weird things(not really) happen.

Your screen's size is probably 640px wide. Let's assume the original picture(picture.jpg) has a width of 1280 pixels or something. When showing this in your UIImageView in your ViewController or UIScrollView, it will obviously scale to fit, or else you wouldn't be able to see the entire picture. If you now use your line of code, then you are asking the cropper to crop out a width of  640 (the width of your own screen and rectangle) from a picture that is 1280px wide. The cropper doesn't care how wide your screen is, it just crops out 640px from a 1280px wide image because that's what you told it to do. This will result in the image being cut in half. If your image is scaled down (which it is by default, I guess), you'll need to use this scale in your line of code. If the original picture actually IS 1280px wide, then my above code will work, because I double the rectangle's size (The width of your view is probably 320, this is the same as 640 retina I believe).

If you multiply self.view.fram.size.width and height by the amount the picture has been zoomed, you should get the correct image. This also applies to the "static" 100.0f you send. For your VIEW it's 100f, but if the image is scaled up or down, this will not be correct. You need to multiply this with the same value as well. I'm sure you can get the zoom-scale from the scrollView or imageView or something.

I suggest testing your app with different image sizes. If an image with the exact same pixel-size as your UIView is tested, I think it will work perfectly, and will confirm my suspicion.

Comment: Thanks ! but does't change anything ! same problem still exists !

Comment: Then it's something you don't know about inside the cropper you are using, I think. You should go through that class-code and find out exactly where it's cropping, and check all variables. You should probably create your own cropper, I don't think you need much code when you already have what you have. I can maybe try to take a look at the VPImageCropper later today, if you don't figure it out.

Comment: @Mc.Lover Can you try with other pictures(e.g camera)? And in your code, where does `image` come from? You are taking a screenshot and calling it `screenshot`, but you are sending `image` to the cropper. Is that perhaps just a typo in the question?
You should try with a proper image-file instead of a self-made screenshot, to see if there's a difference in how the cropper is handling it. The `VPImageCropperDemo` worked fine for me. Can you try saving your self-made screenshot and open it on your mac to verify the size(dimensions) of that picture? Maybe it's something wrong with it.

Comment: Thanks I figure it out !